# How to apply grouping on two columns combine in rdlc report

Tags: c#, sql, reporting, rdlc

I have an rdlc report in my C# application. It is bind by a dataset which shows the result from a Stored Procedure. My report has 4 columns "From - To - Arr. - Depr" as shown
[image: Report data without grouping]

The Dataset has one more column of Date. I want to apply grouping on two columns (Arr. & Dest) combine with respect to Date so that for each unique date, the report shows the values of [Arr.] & [Dest.] side by side. Currently I've applied grouping on these two columns separately and got following result
[image: report with Grouping]

How can I apply single grouping on two columns (Arr. & Dest) combine w.r.t Date so that I got a group of Arr. & Dest columns for each unique date?

Comment: You can group while designing the rdlc

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar Grouping can be done only on a single column, I want to apply a combine grouping on two columns so that my reoprt shows a group of Arr. & Depr. columns for each unique date

Comment: then write the stored procedure accordingly, this will be very difficult to achieve once the data is arranged on presentation level.

Comment: How can I get that result in SQL? Because I guess it is not possible to apply group on columns in SQL? @MuneebZulfiqar

Comment: kindly post your table names and relations. Ill try to make the query for you